# worker_exit of Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, gunicorn, multiple-processes

I am using [Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/) to deploy an Django app.

There is a global singleton variable defined in util.py:

```
global SNS_PRODUCERS
SNS_PRODUCERS = {}
def close_producers():
    logger.info('Closing all producers...')
    global SNS_PRODUCERS
    for name, producer in SNS_PRODUCERS.items():
        producer.close()
```

I would like to call `close_producers` when my app shutdown. I added the following into [gunicornconf.py](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#config-file):

```
def child_exit(server, worker):
    # Join background threads in util.SNS_PRODUCERS
    try:
        from util import close_producers
        close_producers()
    except:
        pass


def worker_exit(server, worker):
    try:
        from util import close_producers
        close_producers()
    except:
        pass
```

My understanding is that, there is one master process, and multiple worker process forked from master process. In each process, `util.py` is imported to this process. So, there are multiple `SNS_PRODUCERS` in these process, one `SNS_PRODUCERS` in one worker or master process.

Each worker process has *ITS OWN* [worker_exit](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-exit) hook. The master process has *ITS OWN* [child_exit](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-exit) hook.

When one worker is shutdown, its `worker_exit` is called, and then *ITS OWN* `SNS_PRODUCERS` is closed. Other `SNS_PRODUCERS` are still open.

Am I right? Any corrections are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Just one correction / clarification: The master process isn't running any application code, it's a [simple process that manages signal handling](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html).

The [child_exit](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#child-exit) hook is run in the master process, so won't have access to any memory or global variables like `SNS_PRODUCERS` from any child / worker processes.  The only hook necessary here is [worker_exit](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-exit) which correctly calls your `close_producers` method as you illustrated.